# Creating a revertible version of a branch then merging source files from another branch

Tags: git, github, mercurial, merge, bitbucket

I have a limited understanding/experience with version control, however have used it to perform basic operations such as creating a repository, staging files and committing changes in the past. I've recently taken on a project that another developer had been working on up until now, he's using mercurial and his workflow with regards to version control has been as follows:

*Do site edits direct to the development version of the site. Once an issue/feature is completed this can be committed to the development branch Once a collection of modifications has been completed, deemed safe/approved and ready for live, they can be put so by first pushing the changes on dev up to bitbucket and then sshing to the live server, pulling them down, and merging the development changes back into the live branch, and committing the merge.*

The problem that I've found is somewhere along the line the development version has began to differ significantly to the live version of the site. As this is the case I won't be able to merge the changes I'm making from the development site/branch to the live version. To make this workflow viable I'm going to need the development version to be an exact copy of the live version once again.

To accomplish this I'm (so far unsuccessfully) searching for a way to commit a full version of both branches that can be reverted back to if needed, then to merge/replace the development version of the site with the current live site so that they are identical.

If this is at all possible, how? Also open to any suggestions/improvements, thanks.

Comment: "I'm going to need the development version to be an exact copy of the live version once again" - Goddam, **WHY** you need it (and lost all dev changes after latest merge)? Can't merge? Undo uncommited merge-changes and start again... Or modify workflow to more "brain-powered"

Comment: @LazyBadger: Not exactly sure what you're trying to tell me but the Dev version contains many uncommited/merged changes as does the live. I  don't want to lose these changes on the dev version completely and can't revert any changes to the live version...There is going to be some significant changes to the site being made and when I merge to the live I only want the changes I made being brought over.

Comment: "Dev version contains many uncommited/merged changes as does the live" - can't understand this, please elaborate **how repository branch can contain uncommited changes**???

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is to rename development to development-old, and then make a new branch called development based on 'live'

In git, that would look like:

```
git branch dev-old dev
git branch -D dev
git branch dev live
```

Now your old development would be backed up and available, and dev will be an exact copy of live.

You might have to look up the hg equivalent commands..

Comment: Simpler: `git branch -m` (move) to rename the old branch.  In Mercurial, renaming a branch is, well, "not the same" as branch names are stored permanently in commits.  (The equivalent of a git branch is a bookmark.)

Comment: So say that I then wanted to revert all files back to the way they were when the latest commit in the "development-old" branch how would that be done? I'm aware of git commit and git revert but confused as to whether they revert all files or just the changes in the particular commit you're reverting back to.

Comment: git checkout* not commit sorry

Comment: @user1950065: `git revert` adds a *new* commit that reverses (un-does, backs-out) the changes from some *old* commit (same as `hg backout`): probably not what you want.  To see what things were like with some revision, `git checkout revision` (note: be sure the work dir is clean first).  So `git checkout dev-old` to see what was there.  If what you `checkout` is a branch, you're then "on that branch" and can add new commits to it.  If what you check out is not a branch, you get a "detached HEAD"; you can still add commits but eventually they'll go away unless you mark them for saving.

Comment: @torek: OK so what will using `git checkout` on a branch such as dev-old actually allow me to view, meaning will it revert any differences  comparing to the state the files where in from the last commit on that branch? Also if I wanted to replace my directory with the files from the new dev branch that's been merged from live would the best way be to manually delete my files then clone from the new branch (if that's possible) or is there a better recommended way of doing this?

Comment: @user1950065: sounds like you need to do a quick run through the on line [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/) and see what git does, by example.

Comment: Git answer for Mercurial repository?! It drive me nuts

Comment: @LazyBadger: Well you're welcome to present a better answer using hg :)

Comment: @LazyBadger OP tagged it as git :)

Comment: @stellarhopper - maybe you'll *read context*, not only tags? Question is pure Mercurial (or SCM-agnostic for good workflow) and doesn't correlate to git|github tags

Comment: @LazyBadger If you read my answer, I have acknowledged that these are git equivalents and that one would have to look up how Mercurial does it. My _first line_ described the SCM agnostic solution - if you were to read it. If you're so ticked by a git answer why not submit a mercurial answer (something no one else seems to be interested in doing anyway..) - I'm sure it will get many upvotes.